# Terminology for collection of subsets of $G = \cup_i G_i$ (a partitioning) of subsets of $G$ which contain exactly one element of $G_i$ for any i

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, reference-request, set-theory

Let $G_1,\ldots,G_k$ form a partitonining of a finite set $G$, and let $\mathfrak S$ be the collection of subsets of $G$ which contain exactly one element from each $G_i$, i.e
$$
\mathfrak S := \{S \subseteq G \text{ s.t } |S\cap G_i| = 1\,\forall i\}.
$$

It is clear that $\mathfrak S = \{\{s_1,\ldots,s_k\} \text{ s.t } (s_1,\ldots,s_k) \in G_1 \times \ldots \times G_k\}$. Thus, $\mathfrak S$ is isomorphic to the cartesian product $G_1 \times \ldots \times G_k$. Consequently $|\mathfrak S| = \prod_i N_i$, where $|G_i| = N_i$ is the cardinality of $N_i$.

**Question.** Is there a standard terminology for $\mathfrak S$ ?

Comment: $\mathfrak S$ can also be viewed as the collection of complete sets of representatives for $G/\sim$, where the equivalence relation is $g \sim h$ if and only if $g, h$ belong to the same $G_i$.

Comment: @ABanerjee Indeed. Thanks!

Comment: You could refer to $\mathfrak S$ as the set of [choice functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choice_function) for the set $\{G_1,\dots,G_k\}$.